# Is there an se_toolkit version for ArcSDE 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase

I have the one for 9.3 downloaded--is there a version for ArcSDE 10?  So far my 9.3 version of se_toolkit is working against 10 geodatabases, but I've only tried a couple of the tools(sdeping and sdestats).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.
Just look on the ftp site
ftp://ftp.esri.com/pub/staff/vangelo/se_toolkit/index.html
Match your operating system and look for one ending in 100sp0 for 10.0 with no service packs, 100sp1 for 10.0 server pack 1, 100sp2 for service pack 2, and 100sp3 for service pack 3